# ESXi connect to external management network from internal VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, routing

My ESXi server has two vSwitches:

One has a physical NIC attached which I labelled "external".
The other has no NICs attached which I labelled "internal".

My external network is in the subnet 192.168.1.x and the internal network is on the subnet 10.x.x.x.

The management network address of the ESXi host is 192.168.1.10 and I have a guest VM running RRAS with static routes to handle the routing from 192.168.1.x to 10.x.x.x (and vice-versa on my 192.168.1.x router).

VMs are able to access the 192.168.1.x subnet and machines in the 192.168.1.x subnet can access the VMs.

However, the one thing I'm having problems with is that a VM cannot access the management network of the ESXi host. A machine on the 192.168.1.x subnet can ping and connect to 192.168.1.10, but a VM cannot. What do I need to so I can access the management network on the host from both subnets?